# Añadir un np.array en otro np.array

Tags: python, numpy

Estoy pasando un trabajo que tenia hecho con listas, a uno con arrays de `numpy`, pero no he podido agregar una lista a otra, es decir tenia mi código algo así

```
Matriz = []    

for i in range(10)
    punto = [uniform(Rango[0],Rango[1]) for x in range(dimensiones)]
    #Aqui hacia calculo
Matriz.append(Punto)
```

Esto me arrojaba una matriz `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`, pero al cambiarlo con numpy me arroja todo como vector, este es el codigo

```
Matriz = np.array([]) #Tambien intente np.array([[]])

for i in range(10)
    punto = np.random.uniform(Rango[0], Rango[1], dimensiones)
    #Los mismos calculos
Matriz = np.append(Matriz, punto)
```

lo que me arroja algo parecido a esto `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, y no como quisiera, ya intente con insert, concatenate, poniendo corchetes extras pero nada, alguien sabe donde estoy mal? estaría muy agradecido. Gracias.

**EDIT:**
Acabo de solucionarlo haciendo una lista y agregando los arrays de `numpy`, y despues esa lista la paso a un array de `numpy`, algo asi:

```
lista = []
Matriz = np.array([])

for i in range(10)
    punto = np.random.uniform(Rango[0], Rango[1], dimensiones)
    #Los mismos calculos
lista.append(punto)
Matriz = np.array(lista)
```

Aun así si alguien sabe una manera usando numpy puro estaría mejor, quisiera usar solo estructuras de `numpy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de leer la documentación e investigar en Internet me encontré con que puedo usar una estructura vacía `empty` de numpy, que a pesar de estar vacía puedo definir sus dimensiones y así poder agregar un vector con `row_stack` y que el resultado quede como una matriz

Quedo parecido a eso

```
Matriz = np.empty((0,dimensiones), float)

while(True):
    for i in range(10)
        punto = np.random.uniform(Rango[0], Rango[1], dimensiones)
        #Calculo y Condicion de parada para el while

    Matriz = np.row_stack((Matriz, punto))
```

Esto me crea una matriz a diferencia de el metodo `append` que solo añadia los valores y me generaba un vector, espero sea de ayuda si alguien tiene el mismo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Para añadir una fila a una matriz la función es [`np.stack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html). No obstante esta función requiere que la matriz tenga las mismas dimensiones (número de columnas) que la fila que intentas agregar, por lo que el intento de hacerlo sobre una matriz vacía fracasará.

Es decir, esto no funciona:

```
matriz = np.array([])
matriz = np.stack((matriz, np.random.uniform(0, 10, 3)))
```

porque la fila tiene 3 elementos, pero la matriz a que intentas añadirlo tiene 0 columnas.

Según la propia documentación de `np.stack()`, una forma de crear la matriz que buscas sería:

```
matriz = np.stack([np.random.uniform(0,10,3) for i in range(10)])
```

lo que resulta en:

```
array([[7.96177734, 0.29158996, 4.25046824],
       [6.1105705 , 9.48535728, 8.05496796],
       [5.50284688, 4.49215505, 3.14640298],
       [3.33866378, 3.26059627, 9.2278866 ],
       [1.77816053, 0.96688093, 1.83778965],
       [3.205703  , 3.27325782, 7.24608672],
       [5.89202093, 4.80506303, 9.92401356],
       [3.9086772 , 5.73609181, 0.09332197],
       [4.04388334, 8.31835065, 0.59050758],
       [3.10219741, 9.32407007, 5.55092127]])
```

pero francamente, para este caso tampoco veo la diferencia con:

```
matriz = np.array([np.random.uniform(0,10,3) for i in range(10)])
```

que produce el mismo resultado y es básicamente lo que tú haces (pero expresado en una sola línea gracias a las *list comprehensions*).

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el for  va dentro de un while, no ocupo generar todos los puntos al mismo tiempo,  solo uno de tamaño 'dimensiones' cada iteracion y al final del for solo guardar uno, por eso array no me funciona, aun asi creo que stack me va a funcionar, muchas gracias, cuando llegue a la casa lo pruebo y la marco como, respuesta correcta, gracias de nuevo